# Automatic file selection for upload

Tags: file-upload

Is it possible for a website to automatically find a folder on usb stick and upload all the files in it to the web server by clicking only one button?

The problem is that I don't know how to make upload form automatically detect usb stick as the drive name(ie. `G:`, `F:`, etc) may vary from computer to computer, so hard coding path is not possible.

Ps. I'm using `yii` framework for site development, but can add a new page that will handle this in any other language as the client really wants this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Web sites are not allowed to set default files to upload (it's a major security risk!). Also, web sites cannot scan the hard drive/enumerate what file systems exist on a system, again, for security purposes.

It might be possibly to do this with Flash/Silverlight/Java. Java seems the most likely to allow a web developer to do this (Java plugin seems to be quite willing to give out every permission under the Sun).

Comment: I am aware of security risk, but client wants it as he thinks people who cant navigate through folders (uhhhh) will be using the website.
Could you please link any tutorials/hints on how to do that using flash/silverlight/java? I dont seem to be able to find them

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Allowing automatic uploads in web browsers would be a huge security hole so the browsers **intentionally** prevent it. Even if you manage to find a hole that permits it, the browser makers will break it as soon as they find out.

However, if you have an environment where an actual separate program can be installed on the end user's computer you could easily write a program to do automated uploads of specified directories when launched.

Comment: What about flash/java/etc, that Kitsune mentioned earlier?

Comment: The closest you will get in Flash is probably http://swfupload.org/ - and it still requires user interaction. Java might be able to do it using a signed applet that the user grants access to - but the user will have to have the Java plugin installed and explictly grant it the permissions needed. See http://jupload.sourceforge.net/ for a starting place.